# extracting sentences which contain a particular word

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the sentences  in a textfile which contain a particular keyword. I tried a lot but not able to get the proper sentences that contain the keyword....I have more that one set of keywords if any of this match with the paragraph then it should be taken. 
For eg :if my text file contains words like robbery,robbed etc then that sentence shold be extracted.. Below is the code which I tried. Is there anyway to solve this using regex. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/pgrms/Documents/test/one.txt"));
    String str="";

    while(br1 .ready()) 
    {
        str+=br1 .readLine() +"\n";

    }
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['\"]?\\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['\"]?(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher match = re.matcher(str);
String sentenceString="";
while (match .find())
{
    sentenceString=match.group(0);
    System.out.println(sentenceString);
}
```

Comment: How is a "sentence" defined?  Is any `String` that that has a line break at the end of it defined as a "sentence" or are there other criteria?

Comment: @MadProgrammer str is a String which contains entire news about a robbery

Comment: So how do you differentiate between sentences?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i have editted my code and the above code splits paragraph into sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for when you have a list of predefined keywords:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        try {
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input"));
            String[] words = {"robbery","robbed", "robbers"};
            String word_re = words[0];   
            String str="";

            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++)
                word_re += "|" + words[i];
            word_re = "[^.]*\\b(" + word_re + ")\\b[^.]*[.]";
            while(br1.ready()) { str += br1.readLine(); }
            Pattern re = Pattern.compile(word_re, 
                    Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS | 
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher match = re.matcher(str);
            String sentenceString="";
            while (match .find()) {
                sentenceString = match.group(0);
                System.out.println(sentenceString);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

This creates a regex of the form:

```
[^.]*\b(robbery|robbed|robbers)\b[^.]*[.]
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, to check if a sentence contains `rob` or `robbery` or `robbed`, you can add a lookehead after the beginning of string anchor, before the rest of your regex pattern:

```
(?=.*(?:rob|robbery|robbed))
```

In this case, it is more efficient to group the `rob` then check for potential suffixes:

```
(?=.*(?:rob(?:ery|ed)?))
```

In your Java code, we can (for instance) modify your loop like this:

```
while (match.find())
{
    sentenceString=match.group(0);
    if (sentenceString.matches("(?=.*(?:rob(?:ery|ed)?))")) {
        System.out.println(sentenceString);
    }
}
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  .*                     #   any character except \n (0 or more times
                         #   (matching the most amount possible))
  (?:                    #   group, but do not capture:
    rob                  #     'rob'
    (?:                  #     group, but do not capture (optional
                         #     (matching the most amount possible)):
      ery                #       'ery'
     |                   #      OR
      ed                 #       'ed'
    )?                   #     end of grouping
  )                      #   end of grouping
)                        # end of look-ahead
```

Comment: it's not working    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*(?:rob|robbery|robbed))");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(str);
    while (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(0));
    }

Comment: currently my output shows "sentenceString" which has the paragraph splitted sentences...How can I insert reg ex in such a manner that I get the neede o/p..I'm very new to regex...plz help me

Comment: @chopu Just added some Java code to the answer, let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: thanks for spending so much time for me  zx81 ..but it doesn't works

Comment: @chopu At which point is it broken? You are able to split your input into sentences, but `System.out.println(sentenceString);` doesn't filter just the `robbery` sentences? Or you are not able to split?

Comment: @chopu Ah, forget my question, I see you have an answer. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55176/discussion-between-chopu-and-zx81).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/) and icu4j. It does boundary analysis, so it splits sentences and words for you, and will do it for different languages.

For the rest, you can either match the words against a Pattern (as others have suggested), or check it against a Set of the words you're interested in.